# Is it normal to detach persistent objects when they do not need to be modified?

Tags: jpa, orm

I have a spring-boot app that exposes a REST api.  I am using the repository pattern for ORM.

My question is about the proper way to handle persistent objects when I do not need them to be persistent.

Is detaching them good practice?

For example in one situation I might query the UserRepository and then query the BlahBlahBlahRepository, and then do some calculations on the objects and return a result.

However, I do not need those objects to persist and be monitored because they will not be changed.  Do I need to be concerned about the overhead or is there something I can do besides calling detach on those objects.

Comment: This is not a specific question, and this website's format doesn't allow for an hour long lecture on how to correctly implement JPA in Spring. You should read a book and follow it's style guidelines for that.

Regarding your question, stop worrying about an overhead, especially at your level. It is an antipattern to try and solve not yet existing performance issues. First get program to work, and then (only if necessary) start working on making it work faster. In 90% of cases you will never need to, in 10% you will be able to see where exactly the problem lies

Comment: it already works, but i don't want to wait until there are potential load issues before I seek to make a change.

And specifically I asked, "is there something I can do besides calling detach on those objects"